# Real Time Service not working in AX 2012 R2

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to configure AX 2012 R2, Real time service (not the web service)  but during inventory lookup request from POS, it gives an error at POS

error number: 13010 could not connect to the transaction service,

I've checked the event log, which shows the below details:

LSRetailPosis.TransactionServices.InvokeMethod: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing.  ---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: Expected record type 'PreambleAck', found '46'.

Below are my retail headquarter settings:

```
            1. Firewall is completely off.

            2. RTS conguration:

                            Server:AX12-Test

                            Port:1239

                            Protocol:net.tcp

                            Passphrase: i have tried all possbile passphrases.

                            language: en-us

                            Realtime service  version:  AX 2012 R2

            3. Service is listening on the 1239 port number.

            4. As soon as i click inventory lookup atp pos error appears:  error number: 13010 could not connect to the transaction service,

            5. then i looked into the eventlog which showed the following error:
```

1. Below is the transaction service configuration file setting:

```
<add key="Port" value="1239" />

<add key="UseAX" value="1" />

<!--AOSINSTANCE@AOSSERVER:AOSPORT-->

<add key="ObjectServer" value="MicrosoftDynamicsAX@AX12-Test:2712" />

<!-- When both IPV4 and IPV6 are available, set to true to use IPV6. Default value is false. -->

<add key="PreferIPV6" value="false" />

<add key="RetailTransactionServiceAX61" value="RetailTransactionServiceAX61" />

<add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
```

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
```

```
<sources>

  <!-- this registers the listener with traces from a specific source -->

  <source name="TransactionServiceTracer" switchValue="Error">

    <listeners>

      <add name="xmlListener" type="TransactionServicesLib.EnvironmentVariableXmlTraceListener, TransactionServicesLib, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="%AppData%\RetailTransactionService.svclog" traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, ThreadId, Timestamp" />

      <remove name="Default" />

    </listeners>

  </source>

</sources>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your query, answer is
 - Set Real time service version to `AX 2012 Feature pack` in transaction service profile.

---

Steps for using feature pack Commerce data exchange real time service (Formally transaction Service) instead of one provided by R2 which is exposed through Web service.

```
 Step 1: Check following service is installed and running.
     - Microsoft Dynamics AX Commerce Data Exchange: Real-time Service 6.1

 Step 2: Configure key="ObjectServer" value="AOSINSTANCE@AOSSERVER:AOSPORT" settings at following file
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Commerce Data Exchange\Real-time Services\6.1\Bin\RetailTransactionService.exe.config

 Step 3: In AX go to retail->setup->channel integration ->real time service profiles
```

Set following parameters:

```
Server : "ServerNameHostingThis Service"
Port : "1239"
Protocol: "net.tcp"
PassPhrase : "PassPhrase"
Real time service version to "AX 2012 Feature pack"
```